# BakingProblem with Normalmap

Tags: baking, normal-map

so i made this model of a shark and wanted to bake the high poly to the low poly but something isn't working properly. At least the normal map doesn't look right (look at the picture). And yes i lined them up before baking. I just moved them so it is easier to see.
Thanks in advance for the help.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d50hA.jpg

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ya sure. One moment

Comment: Edit: I just tried to upload it a few times but it always stops at like 70%.

Comment: maybe use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hm file is to big unfortunately

Comment: ok here is a wetransfer link since the other methods didnt work for me. https://we.tl/t-TuAZ5Ufe3U (I named some things in German but it shouldn't be hard to understand)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new image for your bake with the *32 bit Float* option enabled
- Shade smooth your 2 objects
- The unwrap of your low-poly is bad, UV are overlapping, so re-unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* mode
- Bake, it should work:

[image]

Comment: alright thanks for the help. Very much appreciated. By the way, i didn't unwrap the low poly one. Maybe it happened automatically somehow?

Comment: your initial shape was probably unwrapped by default

Comment: Ya your right it was the default zylinder. Sorry but im still kinda new to blender ;)